# Prime numbers using Sieve of erastosthenes in C

Tags: c, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I wrote the following program to display all prime numbers up to 150. It is not executing at all. what is so wrong with it?

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int p[150], i, j;

    for (i = 2; i < 150; i++)
        p[i] = 0;

    i = 2;


    while (i < 150){

        if (p[i] == 0)
            printf("%i ", i);

        for (j = 1; i*j <= 150; j++)
            p[i*j] = 1;

        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i*j <= 150` is incorrect, it should be `i*j < 150`, because the `p` array has elements from `0` to `149`. The program gets stuck in an infinite loop because of this.

**EDIT:** The rest of this answer was incorrect, so I've removed it.

Comment: i*j <= 150 was the problem. it should be i*j < 150.. now the code is running fine.. thanks

Comment: `Because j = 1, every number will be marked as having a divisor.` - Actually, his `i` is starting in 2, so `p[i*j]` only marks even numbers.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Since `p[i*j] = 1`, and `j = 1`, every number will be marked `p[i*1] = 1` => `p[i] = 1`. So the sieve doesn't work. `j` must start at `2`

Comment: @QuasarDonkey sorry, there's a mistake in your logic. Since `i` starts at 2, in the 1st loop, `2*j` will result in [2,4,6,8,...]. The 2nd loop will result in [3,6,9,12,...], 3rd in [4,8,12,16,...]. Concluding, this will not mark [2,3,5,7,11,13,...], which is correct after all.

Comment: @jweyrich Yes, I see that now. When I pulled the `printf` out of the loop, it changed the logic subtly. *My* version requires that both `i` and `j = 2`. My bad :(  I can't remove my answer though until it's unaccepted.

Answer (score 4):

1. You're accessing `p[i*j]`, which is beyond the valid *[0-149]* range. The condition `i*j <= 150` will evaluate true when `i*j` is equal to 150, which is off-by-one. It should be `i*j < 150`.
2. The stdout stream is buffered. You need to flush at the end of your loop. Try adding a `fflush(stdout)`.
3. Might be of less importance, but if you care about the resulting array (e.g.: wants to use it later), the value of `p[2]` is erroneously set to 1. However, your program would still print 2, but that's because your loop prints numbers before changing the value of `p[i*j]`. Concluding, numbers get printed correctly, but the values in the array are not entirely correct.

Comment: yeah, logic gave correct answers.. only mistake was i*j <= 150. it should have been i*j < 150.

Comment: @user1825355 Apologies, my answer was incorrect. There is no mistake in the logic. This answer is the correct one. Feel free to change answer (I can't delete it because it was accepted).

Comment: @jweyrich yes, you have a point here.. I am learning C from this ' programming in C' and it was an exercise out of the book. Though  I got the code running, I am yet wondering how the presence '=' was stalling the whole code. it could have given some output till the time things were and i*j had not reached 150. but there was no output at all. straight away, code went into infinity

Comment: @user1825355: What you saw is the result of a value in the stack being overwritten, when it should not be (e.g.: `p[150] = 1`). The fact is that `p[150]` is accessing something beyond your array, which is undefined behaviour. Everything could happen!
You don't see any output because of point 2 in my answer. The `stdout` is buffered. In other words, contents are not really written to the stream until a new-line (`\n`) is written, or the stream is flushed (manually, or when the process terminates). You could also `fflush(stdout)` after every `printf`, or disable buffering with `setvbuf`.

Comment: @jweyrich thanks for your reply.. I am yet to learn about I/O in C. I appreciate what you pointed out ' undefined behaviour. Everything could happen.'

Answer (score 0):

As a learning exeercise, try adding some printf's to learn what your program does.

Also bear in mind that, as jweyrich says, that printf without \n in it will not output anything until (possibly) the program exits.